# Is "gradually" a good adverb for the structure of "kept" + "verb ing"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Is "gradually" a good adverb for the structure of "kept" + "verb ing" to show that something has occurred in a continuous and gradual manner? I wonder whether it is somehow unnatural.

For example:

> 1 After he went abroad, we kept losing contact gradually until our friendship tie got broken completely.

Or is it more natural to avoid this structure and simple say:

> 2 After he went abroad, we lost contact gradually until our friendship tie got broken completely.

If "kept" + "verb ing" + "gradually" is not a good combination, I appreciate it if you could suggest any other alternative sentences and structures for it.

Comment: "friendship tie got broken" is so awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences make sense, but your second sentence is far more natural than your first

The idea of "keep doing something" is that it happens either continuously or repeatedly. The difference is in the choice of verb. If the verb can happen continuously, like "dance" or "watch", then it has a continuous meaning. And if the verb describes an "instant action" that cannot happen continuously, like "break down" or "win", then it means it happens repeatedly.

The verb "lose contact" is an "instant action" verb, but since by definition it requires a significant amount of time to pass before it happens, we can modify it with "gradually". This gives the complete meaning you're intending, so the verb phrase in your second sentence is correct and natural.

When we add "keep" + ing into the mix, it's confusing because it means it repeatedly happens gradually.

Answer (score 1):

To break off our ties of friendship. Not our friendship tie got broken.

However, there's also: until our friendship broke off completely.

That is more elegant and to the point.

- break off a friendship completely with someone.
- our friendship was broken off completely

1. After he went abroad, we **kept losing contact** until our friendship broke off completely.
2. After he went abroad, we **gradually lost contact** until our friendship broke off completely.

If you use keep + verb phrase, you don't need gradually. gradually can precede the verb or come after it.

Comment: What about: "our friendship got broken off completely". Wouldn't "get passive" be more natural in a conversation? I think saying "was broken" is more appropriate in writing and "got broken" is more appropriate in every day speech. Am I right?

Comment: An other question: is there any preference between the active and passive voice ("our friendship broke off" vs "our friendship was broken off")  in here?  Is there any nuanced difference between the meaning they convey?

Comment: Our French got broken off [implies: by some agent], like distance or time or lack of communication. But got broken off and was broken off are the same thing.